# Docker image cannot connect on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using this Dockerfile to create an image and start a container:

```
FROM node:6.1.0-wheezy 
RUN mkdir /usr/src/goof
COPY . /usr/src/goof
WORKDIR /usr/src/goof

RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3112
EXPOSE 31337
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So the image was created and also the container started but when I try to access it using `localhost:3112` is not working.
**Does anybody know what could be the problem ?**

This is the code structure:
[image]

and this is the command how I start the container  `docker run --rm -p 3112:3112 --name rce rce`

Comment: Is your node app work this the same port that you expose?

Comment: @Joseph node is running on 3113

Comment: For node:
Did you try CMD ["node", "server.js"] instead of CMD ["npm", "start"] ??
Also why exposing two ports ? Your server might be running on 31337 Can you check that as well?

Comment: @senarijit1618 so I am using this repo https://github.com/snyk/goof-container-breaking-in and I was following the commands in the readme. This is a repo that expose server vulnerabilities and some of the settings are in the right order, something is missing.

Comment: this is the problem you need to expose port `3113`

Comment: @Joseph the thing is both ports should be running, 3112 and 3113

Comment: @RulerNature Can you share the docker log ??

Comment: @RulerNature no problem exposes both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention in the comments it looks that you expose the wrong port for your node app

so all you need is to expose port `3113` for your app and when you run your `container` will be something like this

```
docker run --rm -p 3113:3113 -p 3112:3112 --name rce rce
```

Comment: Ok, seems to be working on 3113 not on 3112